# Doxygen enum table is generated wrong

Tags: c, doxygen, enumeration

I'm using Doxygen 1.8.10 with default generated Doxyfile to document a C sourcecode.

The problem is that some enum tables are generated wrong. Here an example:

```
/*!Enum documentation
 */
typedef enum tagMODULE__E_SomeFreq
{
    RES_FREQ__0_001HZ        =  0,   /*!0.001 Hz - 1000  s */
    RES_FREQ__0_002HZ        =  1,   /*!0.002 Hz -  500  s */
    RES_FREQ__0_005HZ        =  2,   /*!0.005 Hz -  200  s */
    RES_FREQ__0_01HZ         =  3,   /*!0.01  Hz -  100  s */
    RES_FREQ__0_02HZ         =  4,   /*!0.02  Hz -   50  s */
    RES_FREQ__0_05HZ         =  5,   /*!0.05  Hz -   20  s */
    RES_FREQ__0_1_HZ         =  6,   /*!0.1   Hz -   10  s */
    RES_FREQ__0_2_HZ         =  7,   /*!0.2   Hz -    5  s */
    RES_FREQ__0_5_HZ         =  8,   /*!0.5   Hz -    2  s */
    RES_FREQ__1_HZ           =  9,   /*!1     Hz -    1  s */
    RES_FREQ__2_HZ           = 10,   /*!2     Hz -  0.5  s */
    RES_FREQ__5_HZ           = 11,   /*!5     Hz -  0.2  s */
    RES_FREQ__10_HZ          = 12,   /*!10    Hz -  0.1  s */
    RES_FREQ__25_HZ          = 13,   /*!25    Hz -  0.04 s */
    RES_FREQ__50_HZ          = 14,   /*!50    Hz -  0.02 s */
    RES_FREQ__MAX                    /*!Always the last member of the enum */
} MODULE__E_SomeFreq;
```

This code will be shown in doxygen as: (formatation is lost on copy paste)

Resource distribution frequency to be selected. Note: corresponding distribution period must be a multiple of ME period

Enumerator

RES_FREQ__0_002HZ
0.001 Hz - 1000 s

RES_FREQ__0_005HZ
0.002 Hz - 500 s

RES_FREQ__0_01HZ
0.005 Hz - 200 s

RES_FREQ__0_02HZ
0.01 Hz - 100 s

RES_FREQ__0_05HZ
0.02 Hz - 50 s

RES_FREQ__0_1_HZ
0.05 Hz - 20 s

RES_FREQ__0_2_HZ
0.1 Hz - 10 s

RES_FREQ__0_5_HZ
0.2 Hz - 5 s

RES_FREQ__1_HZ
0.5 Hz - 2 s

RES_FREQ__2_HZ
1 Hz - 1 s

RES_FREQ__5_HZ
2 Hz - 0.5 s

RES_FREQ__10_HZ
5 Hz - 0.2 s

RES_FREQ__25_HZ
10 Hz - 0.1 s

RES_FREQ__50_HZ
25 Hz - 0.04 s

RES_FREQ__MAX
50 Hz - 0.02 s
Always the last member of the enum

I guess you can see it, that the comment values are taken for the NEXT line value instead of the value left to it.

The second thing is that the real physical values are not shown. (0 to 14)

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you use type of comment that documents next member. Try

```
  RES_FREQ__0_5_HZ         =  8,   /*!< 0.5   Hz -    2  s */
```

or

```
  RES_FREQ__0_5_HZ         =  8,    //!< 0.5   Hz -    2  s
```

instead.